# three models with HABTM how to reach the third model from first in one query

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, rails-activerecord

I am having a basic problem of HABTM.
I have three models, Singer, Song, Album

```
Singer <=habtm=> Song <=habtm=> Album
```

I simply want to know how to find count of albums(distinct) which first singer have.
How do we deal with this single problem.
Can I reduce a query to one liner. If there is some better data model that can be suggested that is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Use `:through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many
>   connection with another model. This association indicates that the
>   declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another
>   model by proceeding through a third model. For example, consider a
>   medical practice where patients make appointments to see physicians.
>   The relevant association declarations could look like this:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

---

UPDATE 1:

Try some join tables.

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointment_physicians
  has_many :appointments, through :appointment_physicians
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :physicians, through :appointment_physicians
end

class AppointmentPhysician < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :appointment
  belongs_to :physician
end
```

Comment: Here appointment belongs to one physician but I have a requirement where appointment can belong to many physicians and physicians can have many appointments.
`Physicians <=> Appointments <=> Patients` is the requirement

Comment: Use join tables. Answer updated to illustrate setup.

Comment: This solves the problem for 2 tables. Patients is lost

Comment: I know. This was only meant to illustrate the setup. It's the same idea for Patients.